# "The action you have requested is not allowed" error when clicking on the Connect button using Selenium through VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, csrf

I automated a login access to a site, with Selenium in Excel vba, and after i successfully fill the *username* and the *password*, when i click  on *Connect* button the page is sending this error: "the action you have requested is not allowed".

Is there a way to eliminate this error ?

Comment: Please... Any code?

Comment: I added the code.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
The action you have requested is not allowed.
```

...is the result of a [Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) error.

A bit more about the relevant [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) and your code trials would have helped us to debug the issue in a better way. However, this error is mainly observed when an end user forcefully executes unwanted actions on a web application in which they're currently authenticated. CSRF attacks specifically target state-changing requests, not theft of data, since the attacker has no way to see the response to the forged request.

However, this issue can occur in either of the following cases:

- The config file of the *Application Server* (config.php) contains the following:

  ```
  $config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
  ```

  - Solution would be to configure:

    ```
    $config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
    ```
- The config file of the *Application Server* contains the following when using HTTP:

  ```
  $config['cookie_secure'] = TRUE;
  ```

  - Solution would be to configure:

    ```
    $config['cookie_secure'] = FALSE;
    ```
- Another approach would be to whitelist the URI as explained in [CSRF User Guide](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf):

  ```
  $config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array('api/person/add');
  ```

Finally, as a thumb rule whenever you intend to invoke `click()` always induce a *waiter* for the *elementToBeClickable*

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response.
This is the code:

Sub eoriginal_macro()

Dim bot As New WebDriver, myproducts As WebElements, posts As WebElements, myproduct As WebElement, post As WebElement, i As Integer, productnum As String, clicknum As Integer, mysheet As Worksheet

bot.Start "chrome", "https://eoriginal.ro"
bot.Window.Maximize

bot.Get "/login"
bot.Wait 6000

bot.FindElementByName("username").SendKeys ("username")
bot.FindElementByName("password").SendKeys ("password")

bot.Wait 2000

Set posts = bot.FindElementsByName("username")

```
For Each post In posts

post.FindElementByXPath("//button[contains(@class,'btn-primary')]").Click

Next
```

MsgBox "complete"

bot.Quit

End Sub

The buton is clickable fromthe beginning.